# How can I dynamically choose a database named in a string variable?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I want to dynamically call different database collections in my app based on a string like below:

```
const collection = 'books';
db.${collection}.find()  // turns into db.books.find()
```

I am using ES6, so if there are any easy ways to do this that would be great!  I've been unable to find the way to create this.

EDIT: I am not trying to access part of a object, but anywhere.  I'd also want to do something like

```
${collection}.db.find()
```

Comment: Dynamically accessing variables is usually bad design. Create `name => database` map instead.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  In my current case, I am trying to access database names that I may not know in advance.

Comment: *"I may not know in advance"* In that case how can a variable with that name exist? I'm talking about the `${collection}.db.find()` part.

Answer (score 1):

Every property on a JavaScript object can be accessed using square brackets. Like this:

```
const collection = 'books';
db[collection].find()
```

Comment: I am trying to do this anywhere on an object, not just within the properties

Answer (score 0):

In case of dynamic strings you should use the format

```
db[collection].find() // turns into db['books'].find()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
object.property
object['property']
```

are same.